# scripts in virtualenv hang indefinitely (python 3.5, windows 7)

Tags: python, windows, pip, virtualenv, freeze

I have previously used virtualenv with no problems under Python 2.7 and 3.5. Recently,  I tried to create a new virtualenv and found that calling `pip list` caused an indefinite hang.

Calling any executable `.exe` in the virtualenv's `scripts` folder EXCEPT `python` causes an indefinite hang, which:

- can be broken out of by raising a `KeyboardInterrupt` (Ctrl-C), but provides no traceback (indicating that python has not yet started running the script?)
- but cannot be killed by "End Proccess" in the Task Manager

How do I even start to go about troubleshooting this? So far I have tried:

**Successfully**

- Activating and deactivating new virtualenv's
- Running `pip`, `easy_install` or `virtualenv` under the main python installation
- Trying to run a non-existing script under a new virtualenv (fails with `command not found`)
- Running `python` under a new virtualenv
- Running the python script files (.py) directly that `pip`, `easy_install` and `wheel` commands point to under a new virtualenv
- Running `pip(.exe)`, `easy_install(.exe)` or `wheel(.exe)` under an **existing, previously created** virtualenv

**Causes indefinite hang**

- Running `pip(.exe)`, `easy_install(.exe)` or `wheel(.exe)` under a new virtualenv
- Rolling back setuptools and virtualenv to known good versions (15.0 & 13.1) before creating a new virtualenv
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Python 3.5 before doing the above

The fact I can run the `.py` files directly leads me to believe that Windows is not handling the `.exe` execution correctly - any ideas on how I could reset, change or otherwise fix this?

It is worth noting that I noticed this after additionally installing Python 2.6, 3.3, and 3.4. I have since uninstalled these to try and get 3.5 working again.

Thoughts? I'm happy to provide log files if specifie

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I reinstalled python, and after that my normal pip executable (as well as the one in the virtual environment) gave the same behaviour..

Comment: As a workaround I'm using `python -m pip install foo` rather than `pip install foo` for instance (and I've written a bat script to do this for me, which runs via `pip` instead of pip.exe from the command line) - actually maybe that's what you mean by talking about running the .py files directly

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of running via `python -m`, that also works for me. Good idea on the bat script, that would be useful to have if you've already written one.

Thanks so much for confirming I'm not going mad! Do you have any idea what could cause these symptoms from a reinstall? I presume it must be a lingering code issue, as I'm reinstalling from the same `.exe` as has worked beautifully in the past.